# Spring batch process fails "Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am in the process of migrating data from an old regional database to a new one using Spring Batch. I've successfully migrated data from four out of five databases without any issues.

However, I'm encountering a problem with the fifth database. The item processor for this migration is quite complex, spanning nearly 1000 lines. Can anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve issues in the item processor for a Spring Batch migration?"

I've eliminated all the LAZY fetch types it also didn't help. The item reader I'm using is JpaPagingItemReader, and the ItemWriter is configured as JpaItemWriter. and process uses two databases, reading from one database and write into another database. I haven't configured any data pool sizes. The Spring version I'm using is 3.1.1.

**Console**

```
2024-01-12T20:32:50.580+05:30  INFO 2384 --- [           main] c.b.j.p.p.PermitDetailsProcessorListener : Subsidy without owners 30825
2024-01-12T20:32:50.608+05:30  WARN 2384 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08000
2024-01-12T20:32:50.608+05:30 ERROR 2384 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary). Address already in use: no further information
2024-01-12T20:32:50.614+05:30 ERROR 2384 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step permitMigrationJobSTEP in job permitMigrationJob

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:466) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:256) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:362) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:206) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:241) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:229) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:153) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:165) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:132) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:317) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:148) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher.run(TaskExecutorJobLauncher.java:59) ~[spring-batch-core-5.0.3.jar:5.0.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:211) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:195) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:175) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:170) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:165) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
    at com.codelk.batchprocessing.MigrationApplication.main(MigrationApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary). Address already in use: no further information] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:116) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.begin(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.begin(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:232) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:164) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:420) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Socket fail to connect to host:address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=primary). Address already in use: no further information
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.ConnectionHelper.connectSocket(ConnectionHelper.java:137) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.client.impl.StandardClient.<init>(StandardClient.java:99) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:70) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:101) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:27) ~[mariadb-java-client-3.1.2.jar:na]
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:681) ~[java.sql:na]
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190) ~[java.sql:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

**I've included faultTolerant, but unfortunately, it hasn't resolved the issue**

```
@Bean("permitStep")
    public Step permitStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
                           @Qualifier("jpaTrx") PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                           @Qualifier("permitItemProcessor") PermitDetailsProcessor permitDetailsProcessor) {
        return new StepBuilder(JOB_NAME+"STEP", jobRepository)
                .<Subsidy, PlantingPermitApplication>chunk(1, transactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader)
                .listener(new PermitDetailsProcessorListener())
                .processor(permitDetailsProcessor)
                .writer(itemWriter)
                .faultTolerant()
                .processorNonTransactional()
                .retry(CannotCreateTransactionException.class)
                .backOffPolicy(simpleBackOffPolicy())
                .retryLimit(4)
                .listener(new StepExecutionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
                        ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
                        jobExecutionContext.put("sequenceContext", sequenceContext);
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Based on the error `Unable to acquire JDBC Connection`, it seems like the job is not able to acquire a database connection. Without a minimal example that reproduces the issue, it would hard to guess the cause and help you efficiently.

Comment: Hi, reproducing this scenario is difficult as it occurred only once when I used Lazy loading for some association inside an entity. Although setting LAZY to EAGER fixed the issue in that particular case, the current situation is different. I'm trying to understand why my step retry is not working with the backoff policy. If you can help me with that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Regardless of the backoff policy, is the retry happening?

Comment: no retry doesn't happen just stop the program